# Php Xpath Select rowspan

Tags: php, xpath

I have this table in a website.Take table xpath in php.I want to take information from the table and put the base on the attributes of certain products in OpenCart.

```
 <table border="0" width="100%" style="float:left">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" class="gr">Dimensiuni</td>
                <td class="c3">Dimensiuni (W x D x H mm):</td>
                <td class="c4">138.5 x 70.9 x 8.9 mm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="c3">Greutate (g):</td>
                <td class="c4">143 g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" class="gr">Display</td>
                <td class="c3">Dimensiune Display (inches):</td>
                <td class="c4">5.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="c3">Rezolutie (pixeli):</td>
                <td class="c4">1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.2 inches (~424 ppi pixel density)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="c3">Culori:</td>
               <td class="c4">16M colors</td>
            </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to get information from the table and form an array of the form

```
Array(
   [Dimensiuni] => array(
           [Dimensiuni (W x D x H mm)] => 138.5 x 70.9 x 8.9 mm,
           [Greutate (g)] => 143 g
   )
   [Display] => array(
              [Dimensiune Display (inches)]  => 5.2,
              [Rezolutie (pixeli)] => 1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.2 inches (~424 ppi pixel density),
              .
              .
              .
   )
)
```

I came up here and here I am stuck.

```
$attributeQuery = $xpath->query("//table[@border='0'][@width='100%'][@style='float:left']//td[@class='gr']");
                if($attributeQuery->length > 0){
                    foreach($attributeQuery as $attribute){
                        $attr[$attribute->nodeValue] = array();
                    }
                }
```

This table is dynamic, I want some general.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you, but you could try to change

```
foreach($attributeQuery as $attribute){
                    $attr[$attribute->nodeValue] = array();
                }
```

into

```
foreach ($attributeQuery->attributes as $attr) {
            $array['@'.$attr->localName] = $attr->nodeValue;
        }
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#115448

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for the `<td>` element that has the `rowspan` attribute to get the section.

This can be either achieved by iterating over the rows and only set the section if it's available in the current row and then keep it as long as it becomes available again:

```
// initialize section
$section = null;
foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $row) {

    // sec section only when found
    $sectionTd = $xpath->evaluate('self::tr/td[@rowspan]', $row);
    if ($sectionTd->length) {
        $section = $sectionTd->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }

    ...

    printf("%s - %s %s\n", $section, $name, $value);
}
```

Exemplary output:

```
Dimensiuni - Dimensiuni (W x D x H mm): 138.5 x 70.9 x 8.9 mm
Dimensiuni - Greutate (g): 143 g
Display - Dimensiune Display (inches): 5.2
Display - Rezolutie (pixeli): 1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.2 inches (~424 ppi pixel density)
Display - Culori: 16M colors
```

The other alternative is to use xpath directly to look for that `<td>` element with rowspan and for the opposite case when it is not found, to take the first preceding one that has it:

```
(
     self::tr[td/@rowspan]
    |self::tr[not(td/@rowspan)]/preceding-sibling::tr[td/@rowspan][1]
)/td
```

This does spare to initialize the `$section` variable before the loop, so it's more self-containing:

```
foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $row) {
    $section = $xpath->evaluate(
        'string((self::tr[td/@rowspan]|self::tr[not(td/@rowspan)]/preceding-sibling::tr[td/@rowspan][1])/td)', $row
    );

    ...
```

This again gives the same output:

```
Dimensiuni - Dimensiuni (W x D x H mm): 138.5 x 70.9 x 8.9 mm
Dimensiuni - Greutate (g): 143 g
Display - Dimensiune Display (inches): 5.2
Display - Rezolutie (pixeli): 1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.2 inches (~424 ppi pixel density)
Display - Culori: 16M colors
```

Here the full example code:

```
<?php
$html
    = <<<HTML
 <table border="0" width="100%" style="float:left">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" class="gr">Dimensiuni</td>
                <td class="c3">Dimensiuni (W x D x H mm):</td>
                <td class="c4">138.5 x 70.9 x 8.9 mm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="c3">Greutate (g):</td>
                <td class="c4">143 g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" class="gr">Display</td>
                <td class="c3">Dimensiune Display (inches):</td>
                <td class="c4">5.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="c3">Rezolutie (pixeli):</td>
                <td class="c4">1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.2 inches (~424 ppi pixel density)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="c3">Culori:</td>
               <td class="c4">16M colors</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);


/** @var DOMElement $table */
$table = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0);

foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $row) {
    $section = $xpath->evaluate(
        'string((self::tr[td/@rowspan]|self::tr[not(td/@rowspan)]/preceding-sibling::tr[td/@rowspan][1])/td)', $row
    );
    $name    = $xpath->evaluate('string(./td[@class="c3"])', $row);
    $value   = $xpath->evaluate('string(./td[@class="c4"])', $row);
    printf("%s - %s %s\n", $section, $name, $value);
}
```

I leave to create the array as a little exercise, as the section is now known within the iteration this should be much easier.